# Isn't my book doing this problem about ionic product wrongly?

Tags: solubility, solutions, ionic-compounds

**Problem:**

After adding a $\pu{150 mL}$ $\pu{6.7\times10^{-5} M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ solution to a $\pu{100 mL}$ $\pu{2.5\times10^{-5} M}$ $\ce{FeCl2}$ solution, green colored $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ precipitate is found. What is the ionic product of $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$?

**My book's solution:**

The concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ will be the same as the concentration of $\ce{FeCl2}$. So, using the formula for dilution we can get the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$:

$$\begin{align}
    M_1V_1 &= M_2V_2 \\
    2.5\times10^5\times100 &= M_2\times250 \\
    M_2 &= \frac{100\times2.5\times10^{-5}}{250} \\
        &= \pu{1\times10^{-5} M}
\end{align}$$

In the same way, the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ will be the same as the concentration of $\ce{NaOH}$. So, using the formula for dilution we can get the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$:

$$\begin{align}
    M_3V_3 &= M_4V_4 \\
    M_4    &= \frac{150 \times 6.7 \times 10^{-5}}{250} \\
           &= \pu{4.02\times10^-5 M}
\end{align}$$

Now, ionic product of $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$, $K_\mathrm{ip}$,

$$K_\mathrm{ip} = [\ce{Fe^2+}][\ce{OH-}]^2 =1.616\times10^{-14} \quad \text{[Ans.]}$$

**My observations:**

My book assumed that $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ remains completely dissociated and thus the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ will be the same as the concentration of $\ce{FeCl2}$, and the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ will be the same as the concentration of $\ce{NaOH}$. My book's answer is correct only at the very beginning of the process when any $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ precipitate hasn't formed yet. However, after the precipitate has formed, isn't my book's answer wrong?

Comment: For better site experience, you can find useful [how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). ( Not to be applied to titles ).

See also [upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: The textbook uses a simplified approach with a badly worded task. It addresses the point just before precipitation start. In fact, there should be rather inequality $K_\mathrm{sp} \le  \pu{1.616E−14}$, as it does not say when prcipitation started if mixing was progressive. The constant also does not count with ions trapped in precipitation.

Comment: @Poutnik Edited the question using \ce and \pu using the link you kindly provided. Moreover, if you post this comment as an answer, I'll accept it as my answer.

Comment: Poutnik is right. The problem should have been better written according to : When mixing small amounts of a $\ce{6.7·10^{-5} M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ in $ 100$ mL $\ce{2.5·10^{-5}}$ $\ce{ FeCl2}$ solution, nothing happens. But when $150$ mL of this $\ce{NaOH}$ has been added, the first $\ce{Fe(OH)2}$ precipitate becomes visible. Calculate the ionic product of $\ce{Fe{OH}2}$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbook uses a simplified approach with a badly worded task.

It addresses the point just before precipitation start. In fact, there should be rather inequality $K_\mathrm{sp} \lt \pu{1.616E−14}$, as it does not say when prcipitation started if mixing was progressive.

The constant also does not count with ions trapped in precipitation.